# Calculating an employee's bonus

Tags: c++, finance

How can I improve this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

/*A program that accepts input of an employees' base salaries and years of service. 
Then it also calculates their bonus based on the years of service.
- 20 or more years of service, bonus = salary * 0.1 
- 10 or more years of service, bonus = salary * 0.05
- 5 or more years of service, bonus = salary * 0.025
Also the program should let the user to enter data until they want to stop. */

using namespace std;


int main() {
    int iSalary;
    int iService;
    float fBonus;
    int counter = 1;
    bool okcontinue = true;
    char idontchar; 

    while (okcontinue) { 
        cout << "You are employee #" << counter << " to use this.\n";
        cout << "Enter your base salary: \n";
        cin >> iSalary;
        cout << "Enter total # of years serviced: \n";
        cin >> iService;

        if (iService >= 20) fBonus = iSalary * 0.1;
        if ((iService < 20) && (iService >= 10)) fBonus = iSalary * 0.05;
        if ((iService < 10) && (iService >= 5)) fBonus = iSalary * 0.025;
        cout << "Your bonus is: " << fBonus << ". Enter 'e' to exit or 'c' to continue.\n";
        cin >> idontchar;

        if (idontchar == 'e') return 0;
        counter++;
        system("CLS");
    }
}
```

Comment: At the very least you could copy the formatting that was done for you over on stack overflow so somebody doesn't have to do it for you *again*.

Comment: Don't use Windows-specific stuff like `#include "stdafx.h"` and `system("CLS");` unless you want your code to be totally non-portable i.e. limited to running under Windows only.

Comment: Read this stackoverflow question too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar

Comment: Read this stackoverflow question too for information about using an alternative to cin >> idontchar;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar
To remove a character that has been printed on the current line you can use putch('\b'); // backspace

Answer (score 4):

1. Don't declare variables before you need them:

   ```
   int iSalary;
   int iService;
   float fBonus;
   int counter = 1;
   bool okcontinue = true;
   char idontchar;
   ```

   By declaring them at the point of first use you also see that they are correctly initialized. Rather than having to scan all the way up the function to the top.
2. Sure if this works for you:

   ```
   system("CLS");
   ```

   But it's not portable. Don't worry too much a bout clearing the screen (or learn to use a platform agnostic library like ncurses or equivalent).
3. Tidy up your condition: (Nornagest nearly has it correct he needs to reverse the order and put in the else condition otherwise somebody with `iService` of >= 20 is going to be very happy with multiple bonus.)

   ```
   if      (iService >= 20) { fBonus = iSalary * 0.1;   }
   else if (iService >= 10) { fBonus = iSalary * 0.05;  }
   else if (iService >= 5)  { fBonus = iSalary * 0.025; }
   ```
4. Floating point has rounding problems. Businesses do not like this. They would prefer things stay exact. So you may want to use integers instead of floats. But track the salary in pennies rather than dollars.